# how to determine the following set is countable or not?

Tags: general-topology

How to determine whether or not these two sets are countable?

> The set A of all functions $f$ from $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$.
>
> The set B of all functions $f$ from $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ to $\mathbb{Z}_{+}$ that are eventually 1.

First one is easier to determine since set of fuctions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}$ is uncountable. But how to determine the second one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: How many different values can a function $f\in B$ have?

Comment: uh, I have some ideas. Maybe I can count the functions in the following way. First we can count the functions that are eventually 1 for n bigger than 2, and then count functions that are eventually 1 for n bigger than 3,...  , does this method work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_n$ be the set of functoins $f\colon \mathbb Z_+\to\mathbb Z_+$ with $f(x)\le n$ for all $x$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x>n$.
Then $$B=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}B_n$$
and $|B_n|=n^n$.

Comment: thanks!!! that is exactly what I have just thought about!